# Help on the Inclusion Exclusion principle and explaining cardinality

Tags: proof-writing

I want to prove the inclusion exclusion principle: |A∪B|=|A|+|B|−|A∩B| where A and B are finite sets.

However I'm confused about one thing. I've learned that two cardinalities are equal if there is a bijection over them... So how would I apply that in this situation?

I guess I can break A U B into |A| and |B| to look at them separately.... like many of the online solutions.

Finding a solution isnt very difficult, but I want to know WHY the solution is doing what it is doing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this by partitioning into disjoint subsets. That is, we'll use the fact that:

> If $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint, then:
>   $$
> |X \cup Y| = |X| + |Y|
> $$

Now since:
\begin{align*}
A &= (A \cap B) \cup (A \setminus B) \\
B &= (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A) \\
A \cup B &= (A \setminus B) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (B \setminus A)
\end{align*}
where any two of the sets being unioned are disjoint, it follows that:
\begin{align*}
|A| + |B| - |A \cap B|
&= (|A \cap B| + |A \setminus B|) + (|A \cap B| + |B \setminus A|) - |A \cap B| \\
&= |A \setminus B| + |A \cap B| + |B \setminus A| \\
&= |A \cup B|
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

On a Venn diagram, the area of two overlapping ovals is the sum of the area of each oval minus the area of the overlap.

The same principle holds for *finite* sets.

The measure of the union of two sets is the sum of the measures of each set minus the measure of the intersection of the two sets.

$$|A\cup B| = |A| + |B| - |A\cap B|$$